# Selecting a piece of data from a table, with the highest value in SQL 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Problem**: I need to display the name, price, and alcohol content of a piece of data that is the highest of its kind in a certain row in my table.

**Attempted Solution**:

```
SELECT MAX(wineSugar_gl) FROM WINE;
```

Where `WINE` is the table name and `wineSugar_gl` is the row name.

**Output from attempted solution**: [Attempted solution output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFAQr.png)

**Question**: What would I add to this code in order to display the rest of the data needed?

**Additional Information**: Below are the row names that I need to display.

```
wineName
winePrice
wineAlchohal
```

Comment: See [Group By](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

Comment: row name  or column name ?   . show you table schema and a data sample

Comment: @scaisEdge can you specify your first question please?

Comment: You refer to : wineSugar_gl is the row name.     .. and i ask if this is the column name or the name of a key in a row of your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get some aggregate value (like MAX()), *and* you want other fields **from the same row**, a very popular and efficient method is to use the `row_number()` function, like this:

```
SELECT wineName, winePrice, wineAlchohal, wineSugar_gl 
FROM (
     SELECT wineName, winePrice, wineAlchohal, wineSugar_gl,
         row_number() over (order by wineSugar_gl desc) as seqnum
     FROM WINE
) x
where seqnum = 1 
--since we ordered by wineSugar_gl descending, seqnum 1 is equivalent 
--to max(wineSugar_gl), and you can also get other fields from that row
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
SELECT wineName, winePrice, wineAlchohal, MAX(wineSugar_gl) FROM WINE group by wineName, winePrice, wineAlchohal
```